# How to get the current route value within Web config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, custom-error-handling

I have a multilanguage site. This means that I need redirect my visitor to error pages with appropriate language like so:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ru/Error">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ru/404"/>
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ru/500"/>
</customErrors>
```

or:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/en/Error">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/en/404"/>
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/en/500"/>
</customErrors>
```

depending on language of the previous page or localization. By default it's 'en'. I have `RouteData.Values["lang"]` for my language value.

Comment: I don't think you can do something like that with just custom errors, but you could redirect to more generic handler/controller and then either server.transfer or redirect from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific folders for your project files by language,

you should create web.config file under all project folders. And customize your all webconfig files' `<customErrors/>` tags.

See an example below:

```
ru
 .....
 .......
 web.config

en
  .....
  .......
  web.config
```